# Dúvida em como usar "!="

Tags: android

Algumas vezes me deparo com o ponto de exclamação `!` antes do caractere igual `=`e sempre fico com uma dúvida de o porquê ter ele ali. Pequeno exemplo:

```
if (model.getFile() != null){
```

Sei que se o resultado de `model.getFile()` for `true`  segue o codigo, mas o que `!` faz explicitamente?

Comment: negação: Leia-se `se(model.getFile() é diferente de null))`

Comment: então se tiver , = , Leia-se `se(model.getFile() é igual  null))`

Comment: Acesse um dos links marcados como duplicata, nele tem uma explicação mais detalhada.

Comment: Não, o oposto de `!=` é `==`.

Comment: assim, agora entendo... e se tiver somente `=` ?

Comment: Ai é atribuição e não comparação.

Comment: Wallace, o ponto de exclamação basicamente inverte o valor da condição, por exemplo: `!true` sera verificado se é `false`, e junto com o simbolo de igual a lógica é a mesma: `==` (é igual), `!=` (é diferente)

Comment: interessante entedi , tentei pesquisar antes mais não sabia como perguntar ao google :) ,Valeu.

Comment: @Jefferson Quesado , burrice minha dizer que ! era interrogação , valeu pela correção.